# ansible module for timeout in conjunction with shell

Tags: ansible

After executing a shell command to change the node IP address of the node which I am connected to, connection gets lost (obviously). So control gets stuck at that particular task. How do I get past that task

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: ESX IP change

    shell: esxcli network ip interface ipv4 set -i vmk0 -I "{{item.esxNew}}" -N "{{esxNetmask}}" -t static &

    delegate_to: "{{item.esxOld}}"

    async: 10

    poll: 5

    with_items:
      "{{nodeDetails}}"
```

Current results -

```
TASK [ESX IP change] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Expected results -

```
TASK [ESX IP change] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use timeout per tasks basis Like below:-

```
 vars:
   ansible_command_timeout: 40
```

[timeout_reference_link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42200)

Comment: This doesn't work for shell tasks. It just sets a variable but doesn't set a timeout for the task.